# convert string into date format in java

Tags: java, jcalendar

I want to convert this string to the following date format.

```
  String s = "2-26-2013";
  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM/dd/yyyy").parse(s);
  System.out.println(date);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2-26-2013"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes. The argument you pass into the constructor of `SimpleDateFormat` says the format you expect the date to be in.

`"EEEE, MMMM/dd/yyyy"` would be valid for input like "Tuesday, February/26/2013". It's not even *slightly* valid for "2-26-2013". You do understand that you're *parsing* the text at the moment, not formatting it?

It looks like you want a format string of "M-dd-yyyy" or possibly "M-d-yyyy".

If you're trying to convert from one format to another, you need to first specify the format to parse, and then specify the format to format with:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = parser.parse(input);
String output = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: any suggestions, i just want to convert the string in a suitable format so that i can retrieve them by year.

Comment: what do you mean "retrieve them by year"? DO you mean extract the year part of the date?

Comment: @MuhsinaM: What do you mean by "retrieve them by year"? What does that have to do with formatting as text?

Comment: actually when i'm converting them to date, i'm storing it in a database and later another method is retrieving every record based on specific year/date

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(s);
```

The argument to SimpleDateFormat defines the format your date it in. The above line matches your format, and works. Your example does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `MMMM/dd/yyyy` you need to used `MM-dd-yyyy`. SimpleDateFormat expects the pattern to match what its trying to parse.