# Jdatachooser does not place the date correctly

Tags: java, jcalendar

I am making a simple form, I have installed the jcalendar library to be able to place a calendar, however, when placing the date it places the wrong month, I will attach an image to show the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lkB8.png)

Search for ways to fix it but I don't find similar problems.

Comment: I have noticed that the month is synchronized with the minutes of the day. That makes no sense

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: For reference, [tag:jcalendar] uses the _Date and Time Patterns_ defined by [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) internally.

Comment: See also [convert string into date format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085771/convert-string-into-date-format-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, apparently it had the date format yyyy-mm-dd and jcalendar detects lowercase m as minutes, to solve it use MM